# Rancher error catalog Remote commit check failed: Repo

Tags: kubernetes, charts, rancher

someone has a solution to this problem in the rancher catalog.

[Rancher Catalog Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkkfP.png)

```
Remote commit check failed: Repo [https://git.rancher.io/helm3-charts] is not accessible: Get "https://git.rancher.io/repos/helm3-charts/commits/master": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

this error occurs when i start rancher with docker for the first time.

`sudo docker run -d --name rancher -v /opt/rancher:/var/lib/rancher --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --privileged rancher/rancher`

Comment: Can you describe when does this error occur?

Comment: it happens as soon as I lift rancher from scratch with docker run

Comment: this happened when I tried to run with docker run, I think I already found the solution apparently another container was occupying port 443, so I used port 8443